# IDLE on windows error PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using IDLE on windows , when i run this below code i get error .

> > > mut = 'F:\Perl\python\Examples'
> > >
> > > file_name = open (mut,'r')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    file_name = open (mut,'r')
PermissionErro`enter code here`r: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'F:\Perl\python\Examples'

'F:\Perl\python\Examples' is the path where my 'mut' file is located.

Please assists i am confused ?

Comment: Are you trying to open a directory?

Comment: `open` returns a file handle, not a file name

Answer (score 1):

'/' can be used on Windows quite happily, and is simpler.

Looks like `Examples` is a directory/folder - it should be a filename.  That is why you are getting the error.

Note that `open()` returns a file handle, not a file name.  What are you expecting this code to do?

Are you perhaps looking for `os.walk()` or `os.listdir()`?